# Configuring ActiveMQ logging on Tomcat

Tags: log4j, tomcat7, activemq-classic

Here's the problem:

I am trying to log activemq network brokers into catalina.out, but I fail.
How to make it work?

Here is what I tried:

I have put **log4j.properties** into

> tomcat_root/webapps/activemq-web-console/WEB-INF/classes

It looks like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq.spring=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.xbean.spring=DEBUG
```

I have on the same machine a spring application that acts as producer/consumer. It puts nicely own application logs (with log4j) into catalina.out. Also in the producer/consumer app I tried to add activemq logging, to no effect.

I refered to this when configuring activemq logging:
http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-enable-detailed-logging.html

Any ideas what to check?

Answer (score 0):

This was missing from the app's web.inf:

```
<context-param>
            <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Then debugged the tomcat log4j startup with flag -Dlog4j.debug

There was one application that was having log4j.jar in own /WEB-INF/lib dir, and that 
messed up the logging.

Removing that jar solved the problem.